# MongoDB: Поиск подстроки во вложенном в массив документе

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, search

### Ситуация

Есть документ вида:

```
{
  ttl: [
    {
      lng: 'en',
      txt: 'English text example'
    },
    {
      lng: 'ru',
      txt: 'Russian text example'
    }
  ]
}
```

Нужно осуществить поиск подстроки в поле **`txt`** во всех документах этой коллекции (поиск должен производится только по этому полю). Например, нам нужно найти строку "**uss**" в этом поле. После поиска должен выдаться вложенный документ:

```
{
  lng: 'ru',
  txt: 'Russian text example'
}
```

Выдался именно этот документ, поскольку у него в поле **`txt`**: "R**uss**ian text example".

---

### Проблема

Написал запрос:

```
db.collection.find({
  ttl: {
    $elemMatch: {
      txt: {
        $text: {
          $search: data
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Но в консоль выдается ошибка **`Error: Can't use $text with Array`** (нельзя использовать оператор **$text** с массивом).

---

### Вопрос

Как можно решить эту проблему без перестроения архитектуры документа? Или же как можно по другому искать во вложенном документе подстроку в поле **`txt`**?

---

### PS

$elemMatch: [Ссылка на статью](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)
$text: [Ссылка на статью](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще идея правильная, но не совсем точная ($text работает ведь с индексами, а у тебя как раз массив ). Вот это должно сработать:

```
{ttl: { $elemMatch: { txt: { $in: [/.*data/] }}}}
```